# how to simply access property of parent class from child class by making object of child class

Tags: php

i am trying to access parent class property from child class, i declared a parent class person, a child class college and made an object Ram of college.It gives error
help please:

```
 class   Person
 {
    public   $name="My name is Ram Singh.";

  }

 class   college extends Person
 {
  function __construct()
  {
    echo"Hello college constructor";
  }

    var   $message=$this->name ;    
 }


 $Ram  =   new   college;
 echo   $Ram->message;  
 echo   $Ram->name;
```

Comment: Can you put the error you have please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It should work. it is tested :)**

```
 class   Person
     {
        public   $name="My name is Ram Singh.";

      }

     class   college extends Person
     {
     public $message;
      function __construct()
      {
        echo"Hello college constructor";
        $this->message=$this->name ; 
      }


     }


     $Ram  =   new   college;
     echo   $Ram->message;  
     echo   $Ram->name;
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to put any variable assignments inside of methods. you can't do it at the class level.

```
class   Person
 {
    public   $name="My name is Ram Singh.";

  }

 class   college extends Person
 {
  public $message = '';
  public function __construct()
  {
    echo"Hello college constructor";
    $message=$this->name ;    
  }


 }


 $Ram  =   new   college;
 echo   $Ram->message;  
 echo   $Ram->name;

 ?>
```

Comment: +1.  You cannot have an expression as a field default value, well spotted.

Answer (score 0):

Your `$message` variable is declared as `var`, you should declare it as `public` to have access from the outside of the class.

A better approach is to make the members of the class `protected` and then code accessors as `getName()`, `getMessage()`